# Java JNA u32t return value of Pointer (Memory)

Tags: java, pointers, jna

I try to access a method of a C++ DLL using JNA.

The Definition is as follows:

```
u32t OpenPort(u8t valueA, char* valueB, u32t* handle);
```

I am not sure how to map u32t and how to get the returnValue using or Pointer or Memory maybe?

I made it like this:

```
int OpenPort(byte valueA, String valueB, IntByReference handle); //u32t OpenPort(u8t type, char* myString, u32t* handle);
```

and calling

```
        IntByReference handle = new IntByReference();            
        byte i = 0;
        int error = myClass.OpenPort(i, "my string", handle);
        System.out.println(error  + " - " + handle.getValue());
```

The result is "0 - 0".

The error "0" is fine, but the returnValue should not be 0. As this is a value I need to pass to other methods like:

```
int ClosePort(IntByReference handle); //u32t ClosePort(u32t handle);
```

if I then start:

```
error = myClass.ClosePort(handle);
```

The return error says that the port handle is not valid.

A sample c# code from the DLL maker is like this:

```
UInt32 handle;
UInt32 error;
error= OpenPort(0, "teststring", out handle);
xError = ClosePort(handle);
```

Comment: Please show the complete binding code (a link to a github repository is fine). The bindings looks sane, so it might be the library setup/options that are faulty.

Comment: Do you really mean `myClass.OpenPort()` or did you create an instance of the DLL as a library, in which case `myClass.INSTANCE.OpenPort()` would be correct?

Comment: Thank you, seems there was a problem in the DLL the code now works fine. And yes, I made an instance before using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

The `Pointer` is actually pointing to native memory where there is a 32-bit value. But mapping just to `Pointer` does not tell you what's at the pointed-to location.

You should use the `IntByReference` class to model a `*uint32_t` or similar pointer to a 32-bit value.  The method will return a pointer, but you can use the `getValue()` method to retrieve the actual value you want.

Also I notice that you've used `NativeLong` for the return type, but it's explicitly specified as 32-bit, so you want to use an `int`.  Only use `NativeLong` for a situation where `long` is defined as 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the operating system bitness.

Note that Java does not have a concept for signed vs. unsigned integers.  While the value will be a 32-bit `int` you will need to handle negative values in your own code by converting them to their unsigned counterparts.

So your mapping should be:

```
int MethodName(byte valueA, String valueB, IntByReference returnValue);
```

Then call with:

```
IntByReference returnValue = new IntByReference();
MethodName(valueA, ValueB, returnValue);
int theU32tValue = returnValue.getValue();
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the solution but the int theU32tValue = return.getValue(); is "0" which seem to be wrong. I edited my questions with the findings. Any suggestion?

Comment: At this point it looks like the JNA code is correct, but without more information about the DLL we can't offer much more help.  What does the return code of 0 mean (success?)  Is the string a valid string to get a nonzero port result, or is the port actually 0?

Comment: Thank you, seems there was a problem in the DLL the code now works fine.